# Do partitions increase performance when only using one computer/node?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark

I know that partitions will boost the performance by doing parallel tasks on different nodes in a cluster. But will partitions help me get better performance when I am only using one single computer? I am using Spark and Scala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will increase performance.

Make sure your CPU have more than one core.

when you making your local sparksession, make sure to use multiple core :

- `local` to run locally with one thread, or `local[N]` to run locally with N thread, i suggest you to use `local[*]`

and make sure your RDD/Dataset have multiple partition, i good number of partition is 2 to 4 time the number of core.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Spark scacles as well vertically (CPU, Ram, ...) and horizontally (Nodes). I assume, that your computer/node has a CPU with more than one core. The partitions are then processed in parallel.